# Google Cloud Storage and temporary serving urls

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, serving

im wondering if its possible to create a temporary serving url for files on Google Cloud Storage.

i have a GAE app and i would like to serve bigger video files over google storage for develpers without 'straming' the files over my appengine app like [here](http://thurloat.com/2010/06/07/google-storage-and-app-engine/).

i would like to have a temporary seving url in my page which gets generated on request to avoid other pages to embed the videos. is that possible on on google storage?
what is the best way to do this?

thx

Comment: Why not use the App Engine blobstore? It's designed for exactly this.

Comment: will i be able to upload a blob of a few 100mb? isn't there a 30seconds limit on requests? or is this not affecting an upload to the blobstore?

Comment: and what about streaming videos and offsets on those files?

Comment: ...just seen it would support that. are there some code snippets to check out somewhere?

Comment: I am having the same question. If Google Storage cant do this, then I have to use Amazon s3 with Query String Authentication.

Comment: @aschmid00 As Nick said: The 30 second execution time limit only applies to the time your code actually spends executing - which doesn't begin until the user has sent the entire request, and ends as soon as you send your response (before they receive it).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look Google Cloud Storage's [signed urls](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) feature:

[Can I do a resumable upload with a Google Cloud Storage signed URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569203/can-i-do-a-resumable-upload-with-a-google-cloud-storage-signed-url/14569208#14569208)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

Each signed url can be set a expired time from 15 minutes to 7 days.

This should work for you.